# How can I get rid of these wrinkles/baggy skin and lines on the model's skin?

Tags: modeling, texturing, shaders

There are some lines and wrinkles on the model's skin which only seem to appear on a randered view, and I have no idea how to get rid of them. I hope this description makes somebody understand what the issue is.

[image] [image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that we can't help unless you can post an image of at least part of the model showing the problem.

Comment: @JohnEason Added an imgur link showing the issue i was trying to explain, those kind of "imperfections" which should not be on the body and I have no clue how to remove.

Comment: Maybe pack the images and share the file (only a part where we can see the wrinkles): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added some images

Comment: Hello, hard to tell without the file, it looks like a normal map?

Comment: Added a somewhat simplified file so you can see. To make the file under 30 MB i removed some textures which made her right arm acquire a different tone, but not her left arm, that may be part of the problem as well. You'll see there's some wrinkles and lines on the model, I just don't know where they come from and how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this node in your material? It's a node group:

[image]

If you select it and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> you'll open the group and see the nodes it contains. The 3D details you show are created by this *Image Texture* and this *Bump* node. If you don't want this effect, just unplug the *Bump* node from the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I also apologise, I know nothing about shaders, sorry for wasting your time, probably a reasonably simple issue.

Comment: You're welcome, nobody is wasting his time here   ;)